# One query to fetch from A, join field values from B as row fields in A and then filter and sort?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, join

I have created the following tables in my database for the purpose of creating an easy-to-reuse-and-configure CMS. I can create a PHP array of objects with any number of any named properties and with this structure it can be saved without having to make tables for every object type. A bit like Wordpress uses the 'posts' table for every custom item type.

```
struct (id, type)

1, 'article'
2, 'article'
3, 'employee'
4, 'article'
...


struct_fields (id, struct_id, sub_id, type, val)

1, 1, 'title', 'string', 'Great article'
2, 1, 'publish_date', 'datetime', '2019-03-02 21:00:00'
3, 1, 'active', 'boolean', 1
4, 1, 'body', 'wysiwyg', '<p>Contents</p>'

5, 2, 'title', 'string', 'Another fantastic article'
6, 2, 'publish_date', 'datetime', '2018-03-01 14:32:17'
7, 2, 'active', 'boolean', 1    
8, 2, 'body', 'wysiwyg', '<p>Cool contents</p>'

9, 3, 'firstname', 'string', 'Jos'
10, 3, 'lastname', 'string', 'Fabre'

11, 4, 'title', 'string', 'This is amazing'
12, 4, 'publish_date', 'datetime', '2018-03-01 19:21:34'
13, 4, 'active', 'boolean', 0   
14, 4, 'body', 'wysiwyg', '<p>Bad content!</p>'
...
```

I'm seriously struggling to create the one query that can take out a list of structs with their related fields as properties.
I'm not sure it's even possible. 
I would like to sort on properties (thus fields in the related table) as well

e.g. I would like to create a query that can grab the latest 3 active articles of which publish_date is in the past.
I've struggled with JOIN and GROUP BY for days now. 
The query for a different type of struct could be ordered by a specific field, or filtered on another field, or both..

So, e.g. for articles I would like the output to be this:

```
[id, active, publish_date, title, body]
```

And then filter on active and sort on publish_date. The id would come from the struct table, the rest of the fields from the joined fields in the struct_fields table.

And for employees it should be this:

```
[id, firstname, lastname]
```

And then sorted on lastname ASC, firstname ASC

In one case I was able to get the struct_field properties into the result row fields with MAX, but I could not sort on them without sql errors

```
SELECT  struct.id, struct.type, struct.published,
        MAX(CASE WHEN struct_fields.sub_id = 'active' THEN struct_fields.vc1 ELSE NULL END) AS active,
        MAX(CASE WHEN struct_fields.sub_id = 'title' THEN struct_fields.vc1 ELSE NULL END) AS title,
        MAX(CASE WHEN struct_fields.sub_id = 'body' THEN struct_fields.tx1 ELSE NULL END) AS body,
        MAX(CASE WHEN struct_fields.sub_id = 'allday' THEN struct_fields.vc1 ELSE NULL END) AS allday,
        MAX(CASE WHEN struct_fields.sub_id = 'start_datetime' THEN struct_fields.vc1 ELSE NULL END) AS start_datetime,
        MAX(CASE WHEN struct_fields.sub_id = 'end_datetime' THEN struct_fields.vc1 ELSE NULL END) AS end_datetime
FROM struct
INNER JOIN struct_fields ON (struct_fields.struct_id = struct.id)
WHERE struct.type = 'events'
GROUP BY struct.id
```

Help! Can this even be done in one query??

**UPDATE**: @Nic3500 [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49071354/one-query-to-fetch-from-a-join-field-values-from-b-as-row-fields-in-a-and-then?noredirect=1#comment85148252_49071354) posting create sql and some sample inserts, so here they are: https://pastebin.com/raw/0hPYByDq

Comment: If you post your table creation commands, with some sample data inserts, we could setup that sample and work on your query must more easily.

Comment: Great, here it is: https://pastebin.com/raw/0hPYByDq

Comment: ;-) in the question please!

Comment: I've updated the question also, and used a pastebin raw url on purpose, so the question would not be even longer than it is already ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if you use alias name for order by

but you could use also the column position  eg:

```
  SELECT  struct.id, struct.type, struct.published,
          MAX(CASE WHEN struct_fields.sub_id = 'active' THEN struct_fields.vc1 ELSE NULL END) AS active,
          MAX(CASE WHEN struct_fields.sub_id = 'title' THEN struct_fields.vc1 ELSE NULL END) AS title,
          MAX(CASE WHEN struct_fields.sub_id = 'body' THEN struct_fields.tx1 ELSE NULL END) AS body,
          MAX(CASE WHEN struct_fields.sub_id = 'allday' THEN struct_fields.vc1 ELSE NULL END) AS allday,
          MAX(CASE WHEN struct_fields.sub_id = 'start_datetime' THEN struct_fields.vc1 ELSE NULL END) AS start_datetime,
          MAX(CASE WHEN struct_fields.sub_id = 'end_datetime' THEN struct_fields.vc1 ELSE NULL END) AS end_datetime
  FROM struct
  INNER JOIN struct_fields ON (struct_fields.struct_id = struct.id)
  WHERE struct.type = 'events'
  GROUP BY struct.id
  order 1,2,3
```

in this way you should be a bit more indendent and you could build a dynamic  range or set for you order by

Comment: Wow, I didn't know this was possible. Thanks. I'm still having errors (column not known) when I try to filter/condition on that alias column.

So, e.g. adding AND active = 1 right after the WHERE clause it gives the error. Is there a way to condition on column number value as wel?

Comment: You must work only on the position  ..not on alias  ... using alias  1 is wrong ..an alias can not be a number  ..  (or start with a number)  ..Anyway the use of number for order by resolve only a part of your needs .. if you want resolve your problems you can't use direct  SQL code but you shoudl build the SQL string dinamycally based  on a set of rules  you define ..

Comment: Would building a query not give me one query in the end? Or am I misunderstanding the concept of "building a query" now? I am a bit further now. I can filter if I use HAVING instead of the WHERE/AND condition

Comment: The question si very broad .. there are several concepts involved .. in brief .. SQL don' allow the use of var for assign object name  .. as column, table ,... and alias .. so you can't pass the order by as you would  .. you could ovveride a bit this using position  .. of the column .. but also this is imited .. But  you must thinks that SQL instruction are string and server side  you can build teh string you prefer .. this is what do the PHP framework for sample od the CMS as joomla or wordpress..  use string for build dinamically the query you ..need ...  hope is clear  .

Comment: Thank you. It is very clear. I'm already building the SQL string in PHP. The question is what would be 'the one' query

Comment: @JosFabre   you comment is not clear  ..  please exaplain better

Answer (score 0):

I think -*probably due to actively diving into this again after getting your answers*- I managed to come up with a solution in this query (in the case of struct type = articles)

```
SELECT  struct.id, struct.type, struct.published,
        MAX(CASE WHEN struct_fields.sub_id = 'active' THEN struct_fields.vc1 ELSE NULL END) AS active,
        MAX(CASE WHEN struct_fields.sub_id = 'title' THEN struct_fields.vc1 ELSE NULL END) AS title,
        MAX(CASE WHEN struct_fields.sub_id = 'body' THEN struct_fields.tx1 ELSE NULL END) AS body,
        MAX(CASE WHEN struct_fields.sub_id = 'publish_date' THEN struct_fields.vc1 ELSE NULL END) AS publish_date
FROM struct
INNER JOIN struct_fields ON (struct_fields.struct_id = struct.id)
WHERE struct.type = 'articles'
GROUP BY struct.id
HAVING (active = 1 AND CAST(publish_date as datetime)<NOW() )
ORDER BY publish_date DESC
LIMIT 7
```